# How to alias sudo in docker RUN command

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I jave the following Docker command that simply runs a bash script called `build`

```
RUN cd dir && ./build
```

However, that script uses `sudo`, which does not exists in my container. How can I make an alias to `sudo` to it resolves to nothing, so `sudo something` just runs as `something` inside `build`, without editing the `build` script?

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to change your script or use a different base image ? You could also just install `sudo` before running that script.

Comment: or you could easily edit the script using `sed` to remove sudo: `sed -i 's/sudo //g' ./build`

Comment: I guess I have to ask, is your question about a solution to different problem (like, you're having trouble editing the file)? This is often called an "XY problem" and it's usually better to present the actual problem while proposing this possible solution so that, if another solution to the actual problem exists, you don't waste time chasing a proposed solution that may not even work in the end.

Comment: Also, [this might help with using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22375610/3393576) and be sure to check out the comments below the answer as well.

Comment: Reviewers: this was cross-posted on AskUbuntu, but the AU question has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use an alias, you'd have to edit the script and add the following at the beginning of the script somewhere above the lines that use sudo.

```
sudo() {
    "$@"
}
export -f sudo
```

---

Alternatively, you could avoid editing the file by creating a new file that doesn't have `sudo`. Then, you could run the new file instead of `./build`

```
RUN cd dir && sed -e 's/sudo //g' ./build > ./buildme && chmod +x ./buildme && ./buildme
```

First, the `sed` command removes `sudo` and the `-e` option echos the output without editing the original file. The output is redirected to a new file named "buildme" using `> ./buildme`

```
sudo -e 's/sudo //g' ./build > ./buildme
```

Then, `chmod` is used to make the new file executable:

```
chmod -x ./buildme
```

and finally, `./buildme` is used instead of `./build`:

```
./buildme
```